# Merge two query results in one table but in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=74315bbb3e4e0c901a5513711cf1743c)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    orderID VARCHAR(255),
    event_date DATE,
    sold_quantity INT,
    return_quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(orderID, event_date, sold_quantity, return_quantity
)
VALUES 

("Order_01", "2020-01-25", "500", "0"),
("Order_02", "2020-01-25", "700", "0"),
("Order_03", "2020-03-24", "800", "0"),

("Order_01", "2020-02-10", "0", "400"),
("Order_02", "2020-04-09", "0", "300"),
("Order_03", "2020-04-09", "0", "100");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date         sold_orders       returned_orders
2020-01-25            2                   0
2020-03-24            1                   0
2020-02-10            0                   1
2020-04-09            0                   2
```

---

In the above table I have `sales` and their corresponding `returns`. 
Now, I want to `COUNT` the `sales` and the `returns` per `event_date` and display them in **two columns**. 
Therefore, i tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
event_date,
COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) AS sold_orders
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
event_date,
COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) AS returned_orders
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1;
```

It already `merges` them in one table but how do I have to modify the query so it gets displayed in **two different columns**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to count the rows where the values are not `0`.  So:

```
select event_date, sum(sold_quantity > 0) as num_sales, sum(return_quantity > 0) as num_returns
from sales
group by event_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e2e6fd46671d683059b66f8673056ffb) is the db<>fiddle.

Comment: It could be confusing having a sum in the answer and a count in the fiddle..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works in the specific case above. However, in my original database I need to query the sales and returns seperately. I cannot combine them in one query. Is it also possible to get the expected results if the queries must be separately?

Comment: @Michi . . . This answers the question that you have asked here -- along with a db<>fiddle that shows that it works.  If you didn't ask the right question, then ask the right question as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If order was sold or returned, at a specific date? the way to know is by the column **sold_quantity** and **return_quantity** . However, we dont want summation of quantities, rather summation of occurrences of each, grouped by date. Hence, I have first marked the columns as 0 or 1, based on if the value present is greater than 0 or not, respectively. And then simple sum on the derived values, will give us result

```
select event_date, sum(if(sold_quantity > 0, 1, 0)) as sold_orders, 
sum(if(return_quantity > 0, 1, 0)) as returned_orders
from sales
group by 1;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

In case the two queries need to be seperated you can go with this one:

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9e2d05ddf5705df2040e5324274162b3)**

```
SELECT
event_date,
(CASE WHEN quantity_type = 'sold' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS sold_quantity,
(CASE WHEN quantity_type = 'returns' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS return_quantity

FROM

  (SELECT
  'sold' AS quantity_type,
  event_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) AS quantity
  FROM sales
  WHERE sold_quantity > 0
  GROUP BY 1,2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  'returns' AS quantity_type,
  event_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) AS quantity
  FROM sales
  WHERE return_quantity >0
  GROUP BY 1,2) t1

GROUP BY 1;
```